# Is it a bad idea to use /128 subnet when a machine is alone in a /64 subnet?

Tags: networking, ipv6, netmask

Example: I got a virtual machine with its own /64 subnet and the default gateway is reachable via a link-local address. In this subnet there is only one machine, the virtual machine itself.

The machine is reachable when I configure a single IPv6 address and set the netmask to 128. Of course a netmask of 64 also works.

Is there any reason why it's common to still use a netmask of 64?